# H2O server init crashing on a different environment

Tags: python, h2o

I have 2 python virtual environments. One is a POC env and has minimal code.
Second one is with the application code base.

The POC works fine. While I try to run with the application code and environment, the `h2o.init()` command fails.

Following is the traceback -

```
Attempting to start a local H2O server...
Java Version: openjdk version "1.8.0_181"; OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_181-8u181-b13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1-b13); OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.181-b13, mixed mode)
Starting server from /home/roopak/.local/share/virtualenvs/xxxxxxxxxxxxx-b0M6BPI4/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h2o/backend/bin/h2o.jar
Ice root: /tmp/tmp9leaDh
JVM stdout: /tmp/tmp9leaDh/h2o_roopak_started_from_python.out
JVM stderr: /tmp/tmp9leaDh/h2o_roopak_started_from_python.err
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "app.py", line 98, in <module>
    application = setup(app, **os.environ)
File "app.py", line 76, in setup
    h2o.init()
File "/home/roopak/.local/share/virtualenvs/xxxxxxxxxxxxx-b0M6BPI4/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h2o/h2o.py", line 261, in init
    min_mem_size=mmin, ice_root=ice_root, port=port, extra_classpath=extra_classpath)
File "/home/roopak/.local/share/virtualenvs/xxxxxxxxxxxxx-b0M6BPI4/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h2o/backend/server.py", line 121, in start
    mmax=max_mem_size, mmin=min_mem_size)
File "/home/roopak/.local/share/virtualenvs/xxxxxxxxxxxxx-b0M6BPI4/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h2o/backend/server.py", line 309, in _launch_server
    raise H2OServerError("Server process terminated with error code %d" % proc.returncode)
h2o.exceptions.H2OServerError: Server process terminated with error code -6
```

---

**Edit: Adding logs**
There was 2 log files created - out and err. err was empty. 
out contained the following lines.

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f51f4a75311, pid=436, tid=0x00007f51f4c66700
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_181-b13) (build     1.8.0_181-8u181-b13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1-b13)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.181-b13 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [ld-linux-x86-64.so.2+0xc311]
```

Comment: Look for clues in the "JVM stdout" and "JVM stderr" files.

Comment: can you run the following command and see if it provides you with a more helpful error message: `h2o.connection().local_server._process.communicate()`. It should return `(stdout, stderr)` pair from the underlying server process and the stderr will hopefully have the message that caused the ABORT signal.

Comment: @TomKraljevic I have edited the question to add logs.

Comment: @Lauren I have edited the question to add logs.

Comment: I was running h2o version 3.20.0.8 - this was crashing. 
When I downgraded to 3.20.0.7 the application is running fine. I verified that this is the version which my POC env is using.

Comment: Is the crash on 3.20.0.8 reproducible? Does it always happen? Can you please try the latest nighty build to check if it affects that build too? http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/master/4432/index.html

Comment: Yes. It always happens in my system. When I try in another machine, this does not exist.

Comment: Instead of starting h2o from python, try starting h2o from the command line:  java -jar h2o.jar  — if it still happens, look for hserror files from java hotspot lying around, or start h2o in gdb and try catching a C stack trace inside the debugger.